# How to check if between two instances of the same class still have the same member as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, equality

I have a class which I use for specifying types like this

```
public class TypeSpec 
{
  // String specifications
  public int? maxLength {get; set;} = null;
  public int? minLength {get; set;} = null;

  // int specifications
  public int? maxInteger {get; set;} = null;
  public int? minInteger {get; set;} = null;
}

TypeSpec typeInitialString = new TypeSpec() 
{
  maxLength = 10;
  minLength = 0;
}

TypeSpec typeUpdatedString = new TypeSpec() 
{
  maxLength = 10;
  minLength = 5;
  maxInteger = 0;
}
```

How do I check whether `TypeSecond` still has MaxInteger as `null`, and trigger false, ensuring that the values being changed here is only maxLength and MinLengthfrom 0-10 to 5-10?

I want to alter the initial type criteria I set with `typeInitialString` with `typeUpdatedString`.. but before doing so I need to validate whether the specification don't contains specifications for other types like an integer? since typeInitialString only used for strings and nothing else

doing ordinary equality will fail as the values can be different, I want avoid the member variables which were previously null still is null in the updated version.

Comment: The default equality comparison is done by compare the reference and that is why two different reference are not equal

Comment: *"How do i check whether TypeB still has MaxInteger as null"* - `typeB.maxInteger.HasValue` ?  It's not really clear to me what you're asking or what the problem is.

Comment: Implement `Equals(object)` and `operator==`

Comment: @David hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

Also not entirely clear on the question. The simple version to return false on `typeB.maxInteger` being `null` will be something like this:
`var result = typeB.maxInteger.HasValue ? true : false;`

It seems though that you trying to implement some custom object equality checks, so you need to have a look at implementing `IEquatable` and the associated overloads:

```
public class TypeSpec : IEquatable<TypeSpec>
{
    public int? maxLength { get; set; } = null;
    public int? minLength { get; set; } = null;

    public int? maxInteger { get; set; } = null;
    public int? minInteger { get; set; } = null;

    public static bool operator ==(TypeSpec a, TypeSpec b)
        => a.Equals(b);

    public static bool operator !=(TypeSpec a, TypeSpec b)
        => !a.Equals(b);

    public bool Equals(TypeSpec other)
    {
        var result = GetHashCode() == other.GetHashCode();
        return result;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this == obj as TypeSpec;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var maxI = maxInteger.HasValue ? maxInteger.Value : default;
        var minI = minInteger.HasValue ? minInteger.Value : default;
        var minL = minLength.HasValue ? minLength.Value : default;
        var maxL = maxLength.HasValue ? maxLength.Value : default;

        var result = (maxI + minI + minL + maxL).GetHashCode();
        return result;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        TypeSpec typeA = new TypeSpec()
        {
            maxLength = 10,
            minLength = 0
        };

        TypeSpec typeB = new TypeSpec()
        {
            maxLength = 10,
            minLength = 0,
            maxInteger = null
        };

        var result = typeB == typeA;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to compare value of properties of typeA and typeB. There are few ways. Simplest is comparing each property. If typeA.MaxInt is null and typeB.MaxInt is null, typeA.MaxInt == typeB.MaxInt wil give you true.